# react-bootstrap-table: How to handle key fields with database generated values?

Tags: react-bootstrap-table

I am writing a CRUD application using react-bootstrap-table to edit records stored in a database table. The primary key is database generated (an `int` field that gets an incremented value when inserting the record in the database). The `TableHeaderColumn` for this field is defined with `isKey={true}`.

I am having trouble getting the insert dialog to work with this. When hiding the column for insert (`hiddenOnInsert`), the dialog reports the validation error "id can't be empty value."

I searched for a way to call a function before the insert dialog is opened, to be able to set a dummy value to the key column of the created row, but without luck.

How can I use the insert dialog with key columns that are database generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you've found your fix but, as [@enkara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/658957/enkara), others might come to the same problem, like myself.

I solved it by updating the row with 'row.pk = newPk' on fetch callback in 'onAfterInsertRow' function:

```
onAfterInsertRow(row) {

    fetch(...).then(response => {
        if (response.ok ) {

            response = response.json();
            response.then((newPk) => {

                row.pk = newPk
            })

            return response;
        }

        return response.json()
    }).then(...).catch(...)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer myself: A function set to the `onAddRow` property is only invoked before a new row is added via the insert row dialog. I use this to write a dummy value like 0 or "" to the key field. I also hide the key field for insert by setting `hiddenOnInsert` in the `TableHeaderColumn`. After inserting (in a function set to `afterInsertRow`) I add the new entity to the database via REST. The REST method returns the new key value. I set this value to the key field of the inserted entity to avoid the bootstrap table to complain about existing key values next time a new entity is inserted.

Comment: Hi, could you explain exactly how you set the value od the id in the onAddRow function? I can't seem to get it right. It enters the method but the value doesn't seem to be set, since the form is complaining about it being empty.

function onAddRow(row:MyType, colInfo: any, errorCallback: any) {
        row.id = 0;
        return false;
 }